# Substring en cadenas en SQL

Tags: sql-server, substring

tengo las siguientes cadenas en SQL:

'|07-48|27-Oct-2021|SP-104|**1162,1171**|2|gdl,tezon,texc,gdl|1171KM |50000KG'

'|05-34|2-Ago-2021|SP-105 |**825,851,852**|4|gdl-villa-tuxtl-oriz-gdl |2678KM |52000KG'

'|07-29|9-Ago-2021|SP-104 |**888**|5|gdl-tex-gdl |1394KM |55000KG'

Las cuales están separadas por pipes (|), lo que requiero es sacar los números que estan en negrito, los números siempre estan en la cuarta posición de pipe.

¿Alguna idea de como hacerlo?

Saludos

Comment: Hola Edgar, te podría ir bien alguna función tipo split. [https://www.educba.com/mysql-split/](https://www.educba.com/mysql-split/)

Comment: Aunque no dices que versión es de SQL échale un vistazo a este link https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16. Como dices que estarán siempre en la cuarta posición las negritas estarán en el cuarto registro.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bastante clásica y que se lleva bien con varias de las últimas versiones de SQL Server es la siguiente:

```
SELECT  F.Valor
    FROM (  SELECT  LTRIM(RTRIM(Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)')))    AS 'Valor',
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.Rn ORDER BY A.Rn)     AS 'Rn'
            FROM  ( SELECT  CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(T.Linea, '|' , '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS Data,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.Linea) AS 'Rn'
                        FROM (
                            SELECT '|07-48|27-Oct-2021|SP-104|1162,1171|2|gdl,tezon,texc,gdl|1171KM |50000KG' as Linea UNION ALL
                            SELECT '|05-34|2-Ago-2021|SP-105 |825,851,852|4|gdl-villa-tuxtl-oriz-gdl |2678KM |52000KG' UNION ALL
                            SELECT '|07-29|9-Ago-2021|SP-104 |888|5|gdl-tex-gdl |1394KM |55000KG'
                        ) T           
            ) AS A 
            CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
    ) F
    WHERE F.Rn = 5

Valor
-----------
825,851,852
888
1162,1171
```

Explicación:

- Convertimos la cadena en una pseudo estructura XML, dónde cada pipe determina un nodo
- Como XML podemos entonces hacer un Split de los nodos para transformar cada valor en una nueva fila
- Numerando adecuadamente finalmente podemos filtrar los valores deseados.